# PHP move file at certain time

Tags: php, pipe

I am trying to move a file from one folder to another at a specific time. In order to achieve this I am trying to use the Linux at command with a pipe :

```
`mv file /to/dest | at h:m d.m.y`
```

This is what I've written:

```
$move = "mv $filename /destination/folder";
$at = "at $my_datetime";
$res = execute_pipe($move,$at);
```

where the execute_pipe function is defined as following:

```
function execute_pipe($cmd1 , $cmd2)
 {
        $proc_cmd1 = proc_open($cmd1,
          array(
            array("pipe","r"), //stdin
            array("pipe","w"), //stdout
            array("pipe","w")  //stderr
          ),
          $pipes);

        $output_cmd1 = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);
        $return_value_cmd1 = proc_close($proc_cmd1);


        $proc_cmd2 = proc_open($cmd2,
          array(
            array("pipe","r"), //stdin
            array("pipe","w"), //stdout
            array("pipe","w")  //stderr
          ),
          $pipes);

        fwrite($pipes[0], $output_cmd1);
        fclose($pipes[0]);  
        $output_cmd2 = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);

        fclose($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);
        $return_value_cmd2 = proc_close($proc_cmd2);


        return $output_cmd2;
 }
```

The problem is that the files get moved right away, ignoring the `at` command. What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Another solution would be a cronjob which executes the php script every minute. The script then checks if something has to be moved.

Comment: http://docs.phplist.com/SetupCronJob.html

Comment: sounds more complicated though, doesn't it? Anyway thank you! If there's no solution to this I'll definitely go with your suggestion!

Comment: Doing it as a CRON job is going to be the only way of doing it using PHP as you're trying to.  One alternative (and awful) way would be to create a PHP script that loops forever and never times out and do the same, but this would consume a thread for something that really doesn't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems like your problem has nothing to do with PHP. You're just using the Shell incorrectly.
The Man page of `at` reads:

> ```
> at and batch read commands from standard  input  or  a  specified  file
>   which are to be executed at a later time, using /bin/sh.
> ```

But your usage of the shell does execute your "mv file /destination" command, and then pipes the OUTPUT of that command to `at`. On a successful moving operation that output will ne nothing. So by using the pipe you actually move the file right away and tell `at` to do nothing at your specified time.

Read the man page of `at` by typing `man at` into your terminal to resolve the issue. Hint: if you want to use STD INPUT, echo'ing your command might help ;)